# Powershell script to download + rename + delete + install [assistance required]

Tags: powershell

I am working on a PowerShell script to run which needs to:

- download from a URL link
- check if .exe exists already and if so, delete it
- check if .exe not exists then download it to c:\users%usersprofile%\Downloads
- finally, run the .exe in backround as silent

Here is what I am trying  but not getting results.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls12"

#Parameter defined
$CurrentFile = "C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Downloads\7zip.exe"
$NewFile = "C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Downloads\7zip_old.exe"
 

#Check if file exists already
If (Test-Path $CurrentFile) {
    #Check if the Target File Exists
    If (Test-Path $NewFile) {
        #Delete the target file
        Remove-Item $NewFile
    }
    Rename-Item -Path $CurrentFile -NewName $NewFile
    Write-host "'$CurrentFile' has been renamed to '$NewFile'" -f Green
}
Else{
    Write-host "'$CurrentFile' does not exists!" -f Yellow
}



## Check the OS architecture and download the correct installer
try {
    if ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem) {
        $downloadURL = "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2301-x64.exe";
    }
    else {
        $downloadURL = "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2301.exe";
    }

    $localInstaller = "C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Downloads\7zip.exe";

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadURL -OutFile $localInstaller;
    
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Failed to get download the 7zip installer";
    Exit 1;
}

## Attempt install
try {
    & C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Downloads\7zip.exe /s;
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Installation of 7zip has failed";
    Exit 1
}
```

What am I expecting:

- check if 7zip.exe exists in %usersprofile%\downloads
- if so, delete it and redownload new .exe file to %usersprofile%\downloads
- if not exists then download the .exe file to %usersprofile%\downloads

then, run the .exe from the %usersprofile%\downloads folder in silent mode

Erros:

Currently this is what I am getting:

```
Action completed: Run Install 7zip Result: FAILURE Output: Action: Run Install 7zip, Result: Failed
'C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\7zip.exe' does not exists!
Failed to get download the 7zip installer
```

The .exe is not getting downloaded at all

**UPDATE**

When pointing the C:\Users\ToMyUserName\Downloads then it manages to download the file .exe however, why does it not work when using %USERPROFILE% ??

Also when using the $env:UserProfile it will point to *C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile* instead.

Workaround:
I may have to point the download to C:\Temp instead... ?

Comment: Please be more specific than "not getting results". Do you see any of the `Write-Host` messages on screen? If so, what do they indicate?

Comment: Hint : Check the value of `%USERPROFILE%`

Comment: Hello Mathias, here is what I get:

Action completed: Run Install 7zip Result: FAILURE Output: Action: Run Install 7zip, Result: Failed
'C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Downloads\7zip.exe' does not exists!
Failed to get download the 7zip installer

Comment: `$env:UserProfile` points to the full path, but you're concatenating it with `c:\users` as if it were `$env:username`.  i.e. Instead of `$CurrentFile = "C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Downloads\7zip.exe"` try `$CurrentFile = Join-Path -Path $env:UserProfile -ChildPath 'Downloads\7zip.exe'` (and the same for other cases where you're going to this directory

Comment: John! Ah, you mean the %USERPROFILE% will automatically go to C:\users\ and therefore wont need to specify the C:\users? hm let me try

Comment: @JohnLBevan I tried by removing the C:\users from the path and get same error:


Action completed: Run Install 7zip Result: FAILURE Output: Action: Run Install 7zip, Result: Failed
'%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\7zip.exe' does not exists!
Failed to get download the 7zip installer

Comment: I suggest after this line `$localInstaller = "C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Downloads\7zip.exe";` you put this line `$localInstaller`. This will print the value of the variable and give you some idea of where the file is going. You need to go through the entire code and sprinkle in various "helper" lines that print the value of variables. You can't just put together a gigantic script first time and hope it'll work without knowing how to debug. Too many things go wrong

Comment: UPDATE:

When pointing it directly to my /username/ it manages to download the .exe file BUT why does not work when using the %USERPROFILE% as I need this script to run on all machines and get it downloaded to the relevant user;s folder

Comment: It doesn't work because powershell.exe is not cmd.exe. Use `$localInstaller = "$env:UserProfile\Downloads\7zip.exe"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen using that suggestions throws this:  
Action completed: Run Install 7zip Result: FAILURE Output: Action: Run Install 7zip, Result: Failed 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Downloads\7zip.exe' does not exists!
C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Downloads\7zip.exe
Failed to get download the 7zip installer

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the $env:UserProfile navigates to: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\  instead of usersprofile.

I may have to use C:\Temp\ folder as a workaround.
The issue then, the script deleting the item ...

Comment: Are you running the script under a system account (e.g. localsystem/networkservice) rather than a user account?  As `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile` is the userprofile for such accounts.  If you want a temp path, rather than hardcoding `c:\temp` you're best off using `$env:temp`; e.g. `join-path -path $env:temp -childpath '7zip.exe'`

Comment: @JohnLBevan we use NinjaOne to remotely install apps on machines, the script is run via the system account with its admin privilege.  As for the $env:temp  are you suggestion to replace this with everything where C:\Temp is hardcoded?

Comment: Personally I tend to use `$env:temp` over `c:\temp` as `c:\temp` is just a folder with no special meaning, whilst `$env:temp` is a recognised temp path, so operations like disk cleanup's delete temp files will include this folder when hunting for files to delete.  Note: The value of this variable is relative to the userprofile, so for a system account will be `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp`.  There's no harm in using `c:\temp`, but unless there's a requirement to use that folder, I'd always recommend using the folder the OS provides for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Because failed to get it downloaded to %USERPROFILE% decided to get it downloaded to C:\Temp folder instead and the script runs as intended:

- checks if the .exe exists in C:\Temp
- if it does, renames it
- checks if the old.exe exists and if it does, it deletes it
- finally it installs the .exe in silent mode

The only thing I am not sure atm is; will the installation simply re-run even when the 7zip manager has already been installed on the device?  My initial instinct does say yep it will reinstall the setup. Any thoughts?

Here is the working script:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls12"

## Parameters defined
$downloadDirectory = "C:\Temp"
$CurrentFile = "C:\Temp\7zip.exe"
$NewFile = "C:\Temp\7zip_old.exe"
 
## Check & Rename file if exists
If (Test-Path $CurrentFile) {
    #Check if the Target File Exists
    If (Test-Path $NewFile) {
        #Delete the target file
        Remove-Item $NewFile
    }
    Rename-Item -Path $CurrentFile -NewName $NewFile
    Write-host "'$CurrentFile' has been renamed to '$NewFile'" -f Green
}
Else{
    Write-host "'$CurrentFile' has been downloaded and will run in background!" -f Yellow
}

## Check the OS architecture and download the .exe file which is version 2301 at moment, which may change in future!
try {
    if ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem) {
        $downloadURL = "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2301-x64.exe";
    }
    else {
        $downloadURL = "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2301.exe";
    }

    $localInstaller = "C:\Temp\7zip.exe"

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadURL -OutFile $localInstaller;
    
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Sorry, it has failed to download the 7zip file!";
    Exit 1;
}

## Call the .exe and install it in background silently
try {
    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $localInstaller -ArgumentList "/S" -PassThru
}
catch {
    Write-Output "The installation of 7zip has failed!";
    Exit 1
}
```